# In double entry book keeping terminology, what is the term or expression for when a journal entry both debits and credits the same account?

Tags: credit, accounting, terminology, double-entry

I configure point of sale software and thus deal with my clients' accounting people. I need to know how to properly express to them this situation, when they describe it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include an example in your question?

Comment: This is called a "no-op" - no operation. No *real* transaction will debit and credit the same account, since there's no change from before to after the transaction. Transaction that doesn't transact - is a no-op, not an operation.

Comment: @littleadv - can your comment be promoted to an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is called a "no-op" - no operation. No real transaction will debit and credit the same account, since there's no change from before to after the transaction. Transaction that doesn't transact - is a no-op, not an operation.